# find in multidimensional array - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 3 by 3 by 2 by 3 array X containing 1s or 0s. Picture this as a row of three 3 by 3 matrices along a row and another such 'layer' behind them (from the '2').

I want to find the positions in X of the 0s in the first layer and second layer separately. I'm not really sure how to do this with find, but heuristically something like:

```
A = find(X == 0 & 3rd index of X is 1) 

B = find(X == 0 & 3rd index of X is 2)
```

**EDIT**

I just realised my attempt to simplify my actual question made it misleading. The array X actually has -1's, 1's and -2's and I want to find the -2's. They're not meant to be logical operators. Also I would prefer any operation proposed to be as fast as possible as this will be part of a recursive backtracking algorithm.

Comment: Do you want the returned indices to correspond to your 3x3x2x3 array, or just to the 3x3x3 subarray independently?

Comment: I want the indices to correspond to the original array please

Comment: Then [Daniel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32682482/5067311)'s your guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**solution using logical indexing**

I recommend to use logical indexing instead of find.
This gives you all indices where `X` is 1

```
value_you_want=-2
C=X==value_you_want;
```

Now you want only parts of these indices in `A` and `B`, first initialize A and B with false of the same size as C:

```
A=false(size(C));
B=A;
```

And finally copy the slice you want to each of these matrices:

```
A(:,:,1,:)=C(:,:,1,:);
B(:,:,2,:)=C(:,:,2,:);
```

If you really want your numeric indices, use `find(A)` and `find(B)`

---

**Alternative solution using linear indices and find**

```
%get all indices
C=find(X==value_you_want)
%convert linear indices to subscript indices, only use third dimension
[~,~,S,~]=ind2sub(size(X),find(X==0));
%Use S to split C
A=C(S==1);
B=C(S==2);
```

Comment: Yes, just what I was looking for:)

Comment: And of course if you don't need the actual indices, this is much faster than `find`.

Comment: sorry again, I realised my question is misleading, actually X contains -1, 1 and -2's. I want to find the -2's. (I changed the question to simplify things but they're not meant to be logical operators).

Comment: @dcwang: Using logical indexing is not limited to logical matrices. It is a [indexing techique which applies to all matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). I updated my answer to be more clear, insert whatever number you want for `value_you_want`

Answer (score 0):

Generally use `find(condition)` to return linear indices in the array satisfying condition.

`A = find(A(:,:,1,:)<1)`

`B = find(A(:,:,2,:)<1)`

Comment: Note that OP is looking for the zeros. And that `find` automatically looks for nonzeros:)

Comment: Note that X(B) will not return the zeros. `h=X(:,:,2,:);h(B)` will return the zeros

Comment: @Daniel and the same goes for Adriaan's answer. I'm not sure, however, which one is needed by OP.